# Checking wether something was printed Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, stream

Is there a way to check whether my python program printed something to a particular stream?

Comment: Are you mean any stream? Not just a stdout?

Comment: In particular stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.x you can try

```
print('print this stuff')


import sys
sys.stdout.write('print this stuff')
```

Comment: But this would only print to the stream write. How would I check it? My situation is more along the lines of, I want a test to check that something printed or not.